# What nuance does "Scientists do not really know." have?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning

> How do children learn? Scientists do not really know.

This sentence is quoted from a certain English-learning book published in Japan.

Does the sentence, "Scientists do not really know.", mean that scientists don't know "almost nothing" about how children learn? If the sentence doesn't have a meaning like that, What is the correct meaning?

Comment: It's all a matter of what "really" modifies. In *Scientists do not really know*, we're being told that ***know*** isn't really / actually the most appropriate verb to describe the current state of scientists' understanding of the process - they've probably got ideas and theories about some of the factors involved in learning, but they don't actually ***know*** very much for certain. Note that in the alternative phrasing *Scientists really do not know*, the word "really" serves as an ***intensifier*** for negating "not" - emphasising the fact that that they ***don't know very much at all***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might mean that scientist don't know everything about the subject, rather than that they don't know anything about it. But it sounds like the beginning of a discussion of the subject, rather than an isolated statement, so reading what follows would probably explain what was meant.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the scientists, do not know a lot about the subject. That can still mean that they know a little bit about the subject.